# What do I earn for playing on Hard or more?

Tags: ps3, tales-of-symphonia-hd

I just got the **Berserker** title, which requires **256+** battles at least on Hard *Battle Rank*. Is there a reward at all I can benefit from for battling on anything but Normal?

Even some simple field monsters manage to beat my characters to a pulp unless I micromanage too much which, along with too much grinding, I totally hate, and I don’t plan more than one play-through.

I’m used to Tales of the Abyss system of Free-Running, so it’s frustrating they get to corner me so easy on this game. Even Tales of Phantasia (SNES) on Hard was easier than this, or maybe it was that Cless was more responsive; I don’t know.

So, yeah, I’d like to know if I can simply switch back to Normal and enjoy the ride without losing anything too important.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really a reward, but it unlock attacks for a few enemies to play hard mode (Abyssion's Time Freeze ability for example)

Also, finishing the game in this mode will unlock the Unknown mode (although it might be by beating Mania mode, not sure)

So no worries, there are plenty of stuff that you can miss in the game, but you won't miss any side quest or plot element or item by using a special difficulty mode